# gmdistribution.fit and .mat files

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I've a very large .mat file which contains a lot of data which I need to visualize. .mat file contains 5 row with each row containing 1x5 matrix - which contains the data. I need to concatenate specific rows together, then apply gmdistribution.fit to it. I'm not sure as to how exactly I access specific elements of the .mat file to concatenate them together.

Say I wish to concatenate first row - > 1st row with 2nd row - > 1st row. How would I go about doing this? I'm new to matlab and finding it difficult to grasp it.

Also, could you explain gmdistribution.fit, please? I read the documentation in their website, however, I still am not exactly sure about the parameters.

Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To access first row:

```
matrix(1);
```

To access second row:

```
matrix(2);
```

To vertically concatenate 1st and 2nd rows into a new matrix:

```
newMatrix = [matrix(1) ; matrix(2)];
```

And you can do this with any row in your matrix.

As for gmdistribution.fit, it is just trying to fit your matrix to a Gaussian distribution. Without a more specific question, all I can do is point you to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html), which holds and explains all the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following, which gave me an error. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? `filename = 'hello.mat';
A = load(filename);
newMatrix = [A(1) ; A(2)];`

Comment: `Error in ==> importdata at 5
newMatrix = [A(1) ; A(2)];`

Comment: `gmdistribution.fit` does not fit a Gamma distribution. It fits a Gaussian mixture distribution.

Comment: Hello. I tried displaying the contents of the row, to see if it is accessing the data. `filename = 'hello.mat';
A = load(filename);
B = A(1);
disp(B);` I get the following result: hello: {5x1 cell}, which is the structure of the file. Might be my fault, I didn't explain the structure of the file well enough. It's a 5x1 (rowsxcolumn) matrix, with each row - when you double click it, contains 10 rows. Each of these rows - when you double click, contains very large amount of data. I'm not sure what this is called, as I have never come across something like this before.

Comment: OK, my bad. They are cell arrays. Sorry, didn't realize data structure like that existed.

Comment: Fixed the distribution name.